# Pandas: Better way to combine rows for 'wide' dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a 'wide' dataset, with one record per game, rather than one record per team, per game. Here's a small example of what I have, first, and then what I'd like to have.

```
   GAME-ID       TEAM  SCORE
0      123  Cleveland     95
1      123    Orlando    101
2      124   New York    104
3      124    Detroit     98
```

```
   GAME-ID      TEAM1    TEAM2  SCORE1  SCORE2
0      123  Cleveland  Orlando      95     101
1      124   New York  Detroit     104      98
```

I can set a flag for game id count (see below), then later use a for loop to iterate through and set values conditionally, but thought there may be an easier way.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'GAME-ID':[123, 123, 124, 124],
         'TEAM':['Cleveland', 'Orlando', 'New York', 'Detroit'],
         'SCORE':[95, 101, 104, 98]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df['GAME_ID_CT'] = df.groupby('GAME-ID').cumcount() + 1
print(df)
```

Result from code above:

```
   GAME-ID       TEAM  SCORE  GAME_ID_CT
0      123  Cleveland     95           1
1      123    Orlando    101           2
2      124   New York    104           1
3      124    Detroit     98           2
```

If there's a way to do this by column rather than a bunch of loops, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pivot`:

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='GAME-ID',columns='GAME_ID_CT')

# rename
new_df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a,b in new_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
             TEAM1    TEAM2  SCORE1  SCORE2
GAME-ID                                    
123      Cleveland  Orlando      95     101
124       New York  Detroit     104      98
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually worked best for me. It's simple and accommodates lots more variables.

```
df1 = df[df['GAME_ID_CT'] == 1]
df2 = df[df['GAME_ID_CT'] == 2]

new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='GAME-ID', suffixes=['1', '2'])
print(new_df)

   GAME-ID      TEAM1  SCORE1  GAME_ID_CT1    TEAM2  SCORE2  GAME_ID_CT2
0      123  Cleveland      95            1  Orlando     101            2
1      124   New York     104            1  Detroit      98            2
```